# Closing manually triggered Bootstrap 4 Popper.js Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, tooltip, popper.js

I trigger a Bootstrap 4 Popper.js Tooltip with jQuery like this:

$('.like-btn').on('click',function(){$(this).tooltip('show');});

The tooltip should disappear after a few seconds. The following solutions did not work:

// 1
$('.like-btn').on('click',function({$(this).tooltip('show').delay(2000).tooltip('hide');});
// 2
$('.like-btn').on('click',function(){$(this).tooltip({delay{show:0,hide:2000}});});
// 3
...; setTimeout($('.like-btn').tooltip('hide'), 2000);

Answer (score 1):

`tooltip('show')` returns the DOM element which it was called on. Also you should not call directly `tooltip('show')` because then tooltip will behave like regular tooltip instead you need to inform bootstrap that you want to trigger it manually

```
$(function () {

    $('.like-btn').tooltip({ trigger: 'manual'}); //inform bootstrap that we wish to handle programtically

    $('.like-btn').on('click',function(){
        $(this).tooltip('show');//show

        setTimeout(()=>{
            $(this).tooltip('hide'); // hides when timeouts
        }, 2000);

    }); 

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but did not work so far.

This is what I got (complete code - tooltrip should be triggerd by clicking on the surrounding div):

$('.like-btn').parent('.item_wrapper,.subitem_wrapper').on('click',function(){
$(this).children('.like-btn').tooltip({ trigger: 'manual'});
$(this).children('.like-btn').tooltip('show');
setTimeout(()=>{$(this).tooltip('hide');}, 2000);});
});

Comment: You have any demo or something?

Comment: Sorry, not yet online. I helped myself with the following solution in the meantime:

Comment: // show/hide tooltip on wrapper mouse enter  
$('.like-btn').parent('.item_wrapper,.subitem_wrapper').on({  
mouseenter: function () { $(this).children('.like-btn').tooltip('show'); },  
mouseleave: function () { $(this).children('.like-btn').tooltip('hide'); }  
});  

jQery delay() seems to be working under certain circumstances only. Don't know why vanilla JavaScript with setTimeout does not work either in this case.  
  
Will post a solution for the initial issue, if I find one. You can always use my posted code for testing ...

Answer (score 0):

You can set trigger property as 'focus' on the link button like this

$('.like-btn').popover({
  trigger: 'focus'
});

Comment: Hi and thanks! Don't know why you use "popover". This is not the syntax I know for current Bootstrap/Popper version. Triggering on focus (of parent element) could be an idea, but was not my initial intention and what I asked for.